# Can't make React router dom work, "InvalidCharacterError"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've litterally been pulling my hair for the last two hours trying to make this simple piece of code work.

Whatever I give the Route component, it gives me the InvalidCharacterError Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document'.

Everything works when I remove the Route, the component Home works by itself.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      Hello !
      <Route path="/" exact component="{Home}" />
    </Router>
  );
}

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>This is the home.</h1>
  </div>
)

export default App;
```

This is the error :

```
InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('{Home}') is not a valid name.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you are passing the component as string which is wrong, you need to pass it as a component, For reference, refer to [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) documentation.

Refer to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-mountain-2lncr) sandbox for reference

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      Hello !
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    </Router>
  );
}

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>This is the home.</h1>
  </div>
)

export default App;
```